# C# - Insert into SQL Server not making changes

Tags: c#, sql-server

New to C#.

I am trying to do a simple INSERT SQL statement using windows forms.
 What should happen is when the button is pressed it will execute an SQL statement but when I do press it nothing happens.

Is there something I'm missing?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace windowFormsApp_test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'por_testDataSet.tbl_persons' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.tbl_personsTableAdapter.Fill(this.por_testDataSet.tbl_persons);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=DC-POR\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=por_test;Integrated Security=True;";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

            con.Open();

            string sql = "INSERT into tbl_persons (person_id,p_name,p_surname) VALUES (55,'TEST','test')";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);

            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You need to execute the SQL command.  Consult any introductory book, tutorial or guide for more info.  Also read the part on connection pooling

Comment: You need to call [ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `SqlCommand` otherwise it's not actually doing anything! Consider reading something like [this](http://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/Lesson02) - your code is missing things like `using` or `finally` blocks which could cause connection leaks and memory issues longer term!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `ExecuteNonQuery` to actually do the insert.

The code should be as follows:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string connectionString = "Data Source=DC-POR\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=por_test;Integrated Security=True;";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();

        string sql = "INSERT into tbl_persons (person_id,p_name,p_surname) VALUES (55,'TEST','test')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
```

You shouldn't pass the values directly to the insert statements. Rather you should use the parameters.add to pass the value. So better approach to execute the SQL is below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString = "Data Source=DC-POR\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=por_test;Integrated Security=True;";

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {             
        string sql = @"INSERT into tbl_persons (person_id, p_name, p_surname) VALUES (@param1, @param2, @param3)";

       using(var cmd = new SqlCommand())
       {
           cmd.Connection = conn;
           cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
           cmd.CommandText = sql;

           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param1", 55);  
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param2", 'TEST');  
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param3", 'test1');

           con.Open();
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just did that but when I run it i get a message System.InvalidOperationException 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.'

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...